# If $f \le C$ and $f$ is increasing, is it true that $f(x_n) \to constant$ as $x_n \to +\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \le C$ and $f$ is increasing. Is it true that $$f(x_n) \to constant$$ as $x_n \to +\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. This constant is the [least upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) of the range of $f$, which is guaranteed to exist by the [completeness axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a =\sup \{ f(x) |x \in [0, \infty) \}$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then, there exists some $m$ so that 
$$f(m) > a- \epsilon \,.$$

Now, since $f$ is increasing, for all $x >m$ we have
$$
a-\epsilon < f(x) \leq a <a+\epsilon \,.
$$
This shows the **stronger** conclusion that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$$